# Qlik sense custom Extension - filter values from data file

Tags: javascript, qliksense

I am new to the QlikSense environment.

I work with a custom extension, implemented with js (using Enigma and JQuery, only front-end).

The extension is used to create containers with some values ​​chosen from a main list of values.

Now I want to manage a filter of these values ​​in the main list, the filter is chosen by the user; when the user chooses a filter value, the main list should contain only a few filtered values.
The extension is implemented with these dimension objects:

```
"qDim": {
    "title": "",
    "qGroup": "N",
    "qFieldDef": [],
    "qFieldLab": []
}

qDimenListDef: {
    "qType": "dimen",
    "qDat": {
    "title": "/ title",
    "tags": "/ tags",
    "grouping": "/ qDim / qGroupin",
    "info": "/ qDimInfo"
}
}
```

and after the socket call, use this instruction to get the values to show:

```
layout.qDimenList.qItems.forEach (function (row) ...});
```

This method shows all values ​​(they are the descriptions of the articles). Instead I want to show only some filtered values; my problem is that the value of the filter chosen by the user is not associated with this description of the articles (for example if the user chooses the year 2015, the descriptions are in the qvf table with the year 2015, but for now in this extension object there is no association between year and items); so I want to look for these values ​​in the QVF file and put them in the main list.

Must I use the hypercube?

Comment: any suggestions? I have to tie the columns of the objects from the QVF files, now the columns of the tables come with no link between them

Comment: Thanks for well formatted question. Personally, I'd have to dig in to it deeper in order to possibly help. I just don't have the time for it, but I wish you the best of luck! Have you heard of Qlik Community Forums? It's significantly more active than Stack Overflow when it comes to Qlik products. https://community.qlik.com/ - Good luck!

Comment: thanks bananabrann, i have asked same question in Qlik Sense forum yesterday (https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-Sense-App-Development/Extension-custom-filter-values-from-user-choice/m-p/1676624#M51432) but have not any response yet.